# Transparent DNS proxy for IPv6

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, ipv6

I`m looking for some "proxy", which would allow me to hide DNS server in my IPv6 network. I want to redirect incoming request to one vlan interface of border router to specific DNS server based on source interface (please see diagram).

My idea is to use one IPv6 address to:

- request from local network to Recursive DNS,
- external network (internet) to Authoritative DNS.

I'm using iptables with snat/dnat with IPv4, but according to manual, it's not possible to use ip6tables with similiar configuration.

[image: Diagram of my network]

Comment: You do not need to "conserve" IPv6 addresses. Everything can have a unique address. In this case you should use different addresses.

Comment: The thing is, that this could help me to manage routing to specified server without any changes in user settings. Is there really no software which could achieve this? :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you care about isolating these you would give external DNS a different IP from internal DNS. Then they can run on different systems in different security zones.  And IPv6 has more than enough addresses to not have to do hacks like NAT.

All kinds of clever things can be done to network traffic. I just think they are uglier than migrating your authoritative DNS to its own IP in the perimeter network.